# The usage of the modal particle "ja"

Tags: word-usage, modal-particle

How is the modal particle "ja" used? Is it the same as "you know"?

> 1. Ich kann ja den Artikel auf Deutsch lesen.
> 2. Ich kann den Artikel auf Deutsch lesen, weisst du?

Comment: *Voll krass ey ist das, alter, wenn du sagst sagst weisst du am Ende eines Satzes, weisst du?* - What I'm just saying is: German do not say "weißt du?".

Comment: @Em1 *"Voll krass falsch Altaaaahhh, weisst du? Du kannst doch nich einfach alle meine Bros als nicht deutsche diffamieren, weisch?"* Das diffamieren ist hier etwas deutlich fehlplatziert, aber weisch?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### "Ja" as a modal particle

1) In statements, *ja* appeals for agreement (Your example fits here, I believe)

a) by using *ja* the speaker insists that what he is saying is correct

> Wir haben ja gestern davon gesprochen = We did talk about that yesterday

b) In contrast to *doch* as an appeal for agreement, *ja* implies that the speaker and listener have the same opinion, whereas *doch* implies that their opinions do not agree

> Du könntest dir **ja** Karls Rad leihen. = You could borrow Karl's bike (we both know you can)
>
> Du könntest dir **doch** Karls Rad leihen. = Surely you could borrow Karl's bike (perhaps you thought you couldn't)

2) In exclamations, *ja* expresses surprise

> Heute ist es ja kalt!= Oh, it's cold today!
>
> Er hat ja ein neues Auto = Why, he's got a new car!

*doch* and *ja* can be used in this manner to simply express suprise that it's [certain quality], whereas *aber* and *vielleicht* express surprise that how/to what extent [certain quality] it is

3) *ja* intensifies a command: using *ja* in a command can serve as an implied warning/threat, especially if the *ja* is stressed

> Bleib ja hier = Be sure to stay here!
>
> Er soll ja nichts sagen = He really mustn't say anything (or else)!

4) *ja* (*sogar*) can be a focus particle: in a list of nouns, verbs, or adjectives *ja* and sometimes *ja sogar* can be used to emphasize one, similar to  "indeed" or "even" in English

> Er war ein Erfolg, ja ein Triumph = It was a sucess, indeed a triumph
>
> Sie könnte die Aussage bestätigen, ja (sogar) beeiden = She was able to confirm the testimony, even on oath

5) *ja* as the affirmative particle

> Es geht um acht los, ja? = We're starting at eight, yes/aren't we?

Source: Hammer's German Grammar and Usage 5th ed

Comment: Careful with the "doch"-example... it is only the rebutting of a negative if it is stressed in that sentence. If unstressed it says nothing about whether or not anyone was of the opinion he or she could not use the bike. It just likes to hear "Oh, yes" from the other person.

Comment: @Emanuel - In that case "doch" seems to introduce some new idea, or a proposal to solve a problem like in "Das Auto springt nicht an. Was machen wir denn jetzt?" - "Du kannst doch schnell mit dem Rad hinfahren!"

Comment: @Ingo... that's right but I can use "ja" exactly the same way. "Du könntest ja schnell mit dem Fahrrad fahren.". To me, the only difference is that the "ja" is more sure of itself, while the "doch" wants the other person to agree.... like "Well, you could just go by bike." (ja) , "Well, you could just go by bike, don't you think?" (doch)

Comment: @Emanuel I agree, nice observation.

Comment: can you please add if native german speakers are usually offended by the addition of "ja" or "doch" ? this would be important to know, how to emphasize the sentence without offending by mistake.